# Java using For loop

Tags: for-loop

Create a java program that asks for a random integer value. The program will then display the sum of all the numbers from 1 to the given integer.

**Example of the displayed program:**

```
Enter a number: 5  
The sum of all the numbers is 15
```

Like:

> 1+2+3+4+5 = 15

Another: if you enter a number: 10
So the display is:

```
The sum of all the numbers is 55
```

> 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10 = 55

Comment: What code have you done so far?

Comment: Hello and welcome, just to let you know this site isn't for tutoring help with programming, you need to be able to post something that you already coded, and explain what's not working as expected.

Comment: Sum of numbers from 1 to n is given by `n*(n+1)/2`

Comment: When you are asking question please you should add your code also what you tried

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at this to learn a bit about loops:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/loops-in-java/
And you can learn to get the user input here:
https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_user_input.asp
You can then use the captured value in your for loop testing condition

Comment: As new user you provided a nice, restrained (homework!) answer. Keep that on.